# what does the nowcast.dates attribute tell about the R object?

Tags: r

I am looking at a colleague's R script to learn from it. I notice he has used the `attr(object,"nowcast.dates")` in his script.

While the other attributes like `$names`,`$row.names`,`$factor.vars`, etc. are intuitive to understand I am not sure what to make of `$nowcast.dates`. As the name suggest the output is date but not sure how these dates are fetched.

Can someone please explain to me what this attribute means?

Comment: as you suggest there are a few reserved attributes (see the details section of `?structure` or `?attr`), but you can make any new attributes you want. therefore, we can't be much help figuring out what someone else has done

Comment: @rawr thanks for your comment. I did check ?attr before posting but I didn't check ?structure. I will check it out.

Comment: The answer depends on the object, not all objects have that attribute set. Was it created by a package function? Can you post minimal code showing how the problem occurs?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for your response. I am not sure if the object was created by a package function. There is no problem, I was just trying to understand what or how attr(object,"nowcast.dates") returns an output.  I will find more information from upstream and update/delete the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my colleague explicitly set the attribute in the upstream script just as @rawr mentioned. I didn't realise we could create our own attributes. Now I know. Thanks to @rawr and @RuiBarradas